# How To Set a .json file as a variable for use in window.open (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, json, window.open

I have made a website using **html** and **javascript**. I am Experienced In both, but am struggling with making a button open a website with the url being from a **json** file. So I want to make a json file a variable, then use it with window.open(JSON-url,"_blank"). I then want to make a var called JSON-url and it must be linked with the .json file.

---

I had Searched up many examples, but cannot seem to get the correct wordings. I have tried w3schools, Stack Overflow, Quora and many others. I mainly tried other searches for example, "How To Make JSON a variable to use in window.open javascript", but that didn't work either.

```
{
  "JSON-url": "https://www.google.com"
}
```

---

I bet you there are a lot who know the answer to this, so please, raise your thoughts!

Comment: If the JSON file resides in the file system, for security reasons, browsers does provide API for reading the file system content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about JSON files when using a variable for the URL in `window.open()`. You do it the same as any other URL.

Use the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to read the file, then use the contents as the URL to open.

```js
function openFile(files) {
  if (files.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var url = reader.result.trim(); // Contents of the file
    console.log("Opening " + url);
    window.open(url, "_blank");
  }
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

```html
Select file:
<input type="file" id="txt" accept="text/plain" onchange="openFile(this.files)">
```

This won't work in the above snippet because Stack Snippets are sandboxed and don't allow `window.open()`.

Comment: Sorry to bother but i forgot to mention that the json file must be on the local storage of your computer. I want the url of the json file to be directly editible, maybe for use in eg. Adding A link to take you to a new picture everyday.

Comment: Use a `file:` URL to specify local filenames. But if the web page is not from a local file, it probably won't allow it to open this. It's not specific to JSON, you'd get the same error trying to load a local HTML file.

Comment: Why are yuo trying to load JSON into a window, anyway? JSON is not usually intended for displaying directly, it's data intended to be used by applications.

Comment: it could be any file that is easy to edit by someone who doesnt understand code; i want something in which you could paste links, like youtube.com in a .txt file. it should then load youtube when i click the button containing the window.open tag. Understand?

Comment: i want to open a website containing the url inside a certain file(i don't know the type tbh)

Comment: So you want to read a JSON file, extract the URL from it, and then open that URL in a window?

Comment: Yes! thats what i meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196394/discussion-between-ssrilliant-and-barmar).